# Retrieving firebase firestore documents using pagination right way

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

Because there are more than 5k documents in my firebase firestore database collection so i decided to do pagination using php firebase firestore library in laravel. So that i put a limit value, that is first 100 documents will be fetched then when next button clicked then i will fetch next 100 documents starting from 101-200 and continue this way. So that i need not fetch 5k documents in one call which is very slow.

I was following official youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU&t=446s) about using startAt and startAfter methods as written in [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) , for example a next query look like this using cursors -

```
//$document_snapshot holds the last document snapshot from previous query 
$nextQuery = $collectionRef->orderBy('userId', 'DESC')->startAt($document_snapshot)->limit(100);
```

but in the video it is mentioned that if i use a document snapshot to define the query cursor then chances are that because of weird documents rearrangements or deletion of some documents, I may end up missing some documents in the next query calls or query may not work. I am puzzled.

How do I then effectively retrieve documents using pagination?! I searched through google but did not find any solution yet!. I am thinking the last option is query documents by date comparisons so that i get some amount of documents based on certain date range and i continue this way on next button clicks.

But what are the other best ways and if I am wrong then correct me to the right way. Please reply with examples if possible, not one or two lines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey firebase firestore experts plz answer me

Comment: It all just boils down to what kind of implementation you need. In the video you shared he presents a few options for different scenarios, this is becasue pagination for firebase is not perfect due to its nature in realtime updates, as you can see it depends on what type of app you need. Ask yourself these questions so you can find the right answer.

-Are your users expecting real time updates for all 5k documents?
-Do you expect your users to paginate past 5 pages on average?
-Are the number of reads important to your app?

Comment: -what type of data are you managing, does it change often?

Comment: @diego i considered these options but these options not guaranteed always, so one have to just go for normal paging irrelevant of like if my users goes over 5 pages of paging or not. But i can say - 1. no Realtime updates 2. some document fields may update after a certain time

Comment: If realtime is not an issue, you can take this opportunity to save on queries (time and query count which could mean saving money). Consider a cron job that could query maybe somewhere between 2-4 times a day (could be more depending if you expect the fields to change somewhat often) and save them to a file. This way you can have PHP handle the information in a way that perfectly meets your needs and you can serve in anyway you'd like and even increment document count, you could manage the information quite easily by splitting the query in however many pieces you want to deliver.