How to retreive more than 5000 documents from firestore using laravel
I want to retrieve user's document more than 5000 from firestore to html table, i cant view the users table again because the document is more than 5000  but am getting error

public function history(Request $request)
{
    $page = $request->input('page', 1);
    $nextPageToken = $request->input('nextPageToken');
    $previousPageToken = $request->input('previousPageToken');

    $pageSize = 10;
    $ref = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection($this->tablenamePayment);
    $data = $ref->paginate($pageSize, $page, $nextPageToken, $previousPageToken);
    return view('admin.history', compact('data'));
}

// View (Blade template)
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($data->getItems() as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $item['name'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item['email'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

// Pagination links
<div>
    @if ($data->hasNextPage())
        <a href="?page={{ $page + 1 }}&nextPageToken={{ $data->getNextPageToken() }}">Next Page</a>
    @endif

    @if ($data->hasPreviousPage())
        <a href="?page={{ $page - 1 }}&previousPageToken={{ $data->getPreviousPageToken() }}">Previous Page</a>
    @endif
</div>

please what am i getting wrong here ?
I'm getting this error below
Call to undefined method Google\Cloud\Firestore\CollectionReference::paginate()


Your error is pretty clear in that ->collection(...), which returns a Google\Cloud\Firestore\CollectionReference instance, doesn't have a ->paginate()method... Did you see this in the documentation somewhere? Where's the assumption that this code _should_ work coming from? Are you confusing Google'sCollectionReferenceclass with Laravel'sCollection` class?

i was the one that wrote it , initially i was using this code below  to populate it and it works fine   public function history(Request $request)
{
$history = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection($this->tablenamePayment);
$query1 = $history->orderBy('datePaid', 'Desc')->limit(1000);
//('name', 'DESC')->limit(3);
$historyDocs = $query1->documents();
return view('admin.payment-history', compact('data'));
} but since the document is more than 5000 it doesnt work anymore but rather shows me a blank page when trying to view it

After some quick searching, it doesn't look like there's a built-in way in this Laravel implementation (my now-deleted comment was assuming that orderBy() was the Laravel Builder method, which is likely isn't). There's this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350198/retrieving-firebase-firestore-documents-using-pagination-right-way, which doesn't have an answer, but could work with some custom pagination logic. But yeah, your approach with ->paginate() won't work; the method doesn't exist, but ->startAt() and ->limit() do, which you'll likely need to use.

See the documentation for pagination in firestore.  There is no paginate method.  Use limit() to get the first page of results, then startAt() with limit() after that to continue where you left off.
